# Issues Android Emulator Kernel 3.10 x86_64

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I am facing issues with running Android Emulator with custom build Android kernel.

Kernel Source: *https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish.git*
Branch: *android-goldfish-3.10*

No kernel configuration changes

Compiled using command line *$ANDROID_SRC/prebuilts/qemu-kernel/build-kernel.sh  --arch=x86_64 --gcc-version=4.9*
It compiles successful but when I try to execute it it panics:

Thanks for the help.
Amit Dang

```
C:\>emulator -avd M_x86_64_tmp -kernel $PATH\bzImage -show-kernel

C:\>emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1GB
emulator: device fd:564

HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

serial0 console
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
qemu: fatal: goldfish_tty_read: Bad offset 20

RAX=0000000000000007 RBX=0000000000000000 RCX=0000000000000000 RDX=000000000000
RSI=ffffffff817b6ac9 RDI=ffff88003e9280c0 RBP=ffff88003e871bf8 RSP=ffff88003e87
R8 =ffff88003c8ae900 R9 =00000000ffffffff R10=ffff88003e928000 R11=000000000000
R12=ffffc90000012000 R13=ffff88003e8d2410 R14=ffff88003e928000 R15=000000000000
RIP=ffffffff8127a712 RFL=00010246 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0000 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00000000
CS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00a09b00 DPL=0 CS64 [-RA]
SS =0000 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00000000
DS =0000 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00000000
FS =0000 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00000000
GS =0000 ffffffff81a1e000 ffffffff 00000000
LDT=0000 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00000000
TR =0040 ffffffff81a198c0 00002087 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS64-busy
GDT=     ffffffff81a09000 0000007f
IDT=     ffffffffff579000 00000fff
CR0=8005003b CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001a11000 CR4=000006b0
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=000000000000
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=0000000000000044 CCD=0000000000000000 CCO=EFLAGS
FCW=037f FSW=0000 [ST=0] FTW=00 MXCSR=00001f80
FPR0=0000000000000000 FPR1=0000000000000000
FPR2=0000000000000000 FPR3=0000000000000000
FPR4=0000000000000000 FPR5=0000000000000000
FPR6=0000000000000000 FPR7=0000000000000000
XMM00=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM01=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM02=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM03=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM04=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM05=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM06=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM07=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM08=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM09=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM10=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM11=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM12=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM13=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM14=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM15=00000000000000000000000000000000

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met similar problem as you. I found the problem is because of using wrong kernel branch. My aosp branch is **android-6.0.0_r41**, so the kernel branch should be **remotes/origin/android-goldfish-3.10-m-dev**. pls make you are using the right kernel branch.

Comment: @xuqnqn Hi, how can I find the correspondence between aosp version and linux version? Thanks.